# How to pass Token while calling a RESTful Webservice in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Need to call a RESTfull webservice from Informatica powercenter. it has a never expiring token for authorization.

Tried calling the webservie using HTTP transformation and passing the access token in the header. it works fine and webservice returns the result. But everyone can see the token once mapping is checked out.

How can we manage the token, store in encoded format or is there a away to create application connection to store the token ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we do in Informatica world to protect the sensitive data like password and so on.

You store the value in a file and put it inside a folder.
Make the folder invisible / restrict access to read only for that informatica unix user and rest users have 0 permission.
Once it is done, create a parameter in the file and use that file as a parameter for the informatica mapping, so when ever the mapping runs, it will go and pick up the parameter from the file, which the informatica user can only read, and run the mapping .

This prevents
1. Hard coding sensitive elements in the mapping
2. Hiding the sensitive data from all other Unix users other than Informatica unix user, thereby protecting the data